# How to disable the remember password to browser functionality programmatically?

Tags: javascript, angular, firefox, safari

I know this is quite an old topic to discuss and already answered in multiple thread. But I cannot see none of the solutions proposed working in 2020 February.

How can we disable the save password to browser functionality programmatically.

I have seen threads specifying using autocomplete="off", unfortunately that ins't working now. (works in chrome but won't work in safari and firefox).

I have also added the hidden inputs that also didn't work.

I have also tried the input type to text and mask the inputs (Just trying, am aware of the security risks) but that also works in chrome and firefox, but not in safari.

I am looking for a solution that works in chrome, safari and firefox.

By the way, currently am looking to solve this problem for an angular project.

Comment: There are no way to do it in 2020. You can simulate password field with css `-webkit-text-secutiry:disc` or create hidden second input.

Comment: I have been using `autocomplete="some-nonsense"` which worked in most cases, although can't tell if that is still valid currently.

Comment: @demkovych I tried both the approaches but always failed in safari.

Comment: @Morpheus: I tried but seems it's not working any more on firefox and safari.

Comment: To be honest I don't think you should try to turn off autocomplete. Reason being is that it is user's choice and personally I don't like when I save password in browser just to find out I need to enter my details on the next visit. Very annoying.

Comment: @Morpheus, What I am trying to do is to disable the popup from showing, the save password to browser.

Comment: You can try to create custom `input` with `contenteditable` attribute on element.